# What to do if the border does not affect margin and padding?

Tags: css

I am beginner in web developing I created the div that while user hover this border bottom , border bottom is big but the down div is moves in down what to do that div not down 
Please help

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Put this into the div `box-sizing:border-box;` maybe solve your problem